# Changing MVC username settings on registration form

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm developing a application with MVC.
I'm trying to register a test user with **rui.martins** as username, but I can't.
I get **User name rui.martins is invalid, can only contain letters or digits**.
How can I change this restrictions?

Comment: We're going to need to see some code or something...

Comment: MS MVC does not have that restriction. What type of MVC? What is your setup? Code sample maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
I solved it

public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;

            userManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager)
            {
                **AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false**
            };
        }
```